# How to solve the Minify JavaScript and CSS issue in prestashop?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, prestashop-1.7

when i check my website performance on gtmatrix.com it show me the following issue.

Minify JavaScript and CSS:

There are 10 components that can be minified

```
inline <script> tag #2
inline <script> tag #3
inline <script> tag #4
inline <script> tag #8
inline <script> tag #9
inline <script> tag #10
inline <script> tag #11
inline <script> tag #12
inline <script> tag #13
inline <script> tag #14
```

how to solve this problem plz help me.

Comment: Use a minifier - I use this one: http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/ when I need to do it manually.  Not sure if pretashop does anything for you - it may offer some sort of minifying option in the admin - see this: https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2015/02/speed-up-your-prestashop-store/

Comment: Look into either webpack, gulp or grunt which are tools that can be used to concat and minify your files together. Better than just minification as it allow you to reduce the number of script tag which reduce the number of HTTP requests the browser has to do and improve performance further.

Comment: how to use minifier can you explain @pete

Comment: Can you not read?  There are full instructions with both links above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two way to solve the problem

**First1:** login to admin and go to performance tag and make the setting changes like this

https://blog.dareboost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/prestashop-ccc1.png

**2nd:** find the corresponding files into files directories and the use minifier 
http://www.minifier.org/
and upload and save your files again

Comment: can i know why show me only three option like CCC (COMBINE, COMPRESS AND CACHE) instead of all

Comment: please send the screenshot and which PrestaShop version you currently using?

Comment: its available in old versions below to 1.6, you can use the 2nd method compress your files code and reupload the files. http://www.prestabrain.com/how-to-speed-up-prestashop/

Comment: anyway to find out in which javascript or css have issue ?

Comment: You need to check the path of the file in gtmatrix status.

Comment: can you paste here you website name please

Comment: Go to your themes header and footer files and then find the code something like this <script  src="my.js">  here my.js will be your file.

Comment: Ok Now go to your themes then js folder and start minify js and CSS and reupload it  also check footer

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can do it through the administration of your prestashop shop by going to:
- Advanced Settings -> Performances

Then you go to the block "CCC (Concatenation, Compression and Cache)"
Then you activate: "Smart cache" for style sheets and "Smart cache" for JavaScript code

Regards,

Comment: In my admin panel display on three option CCC and do not show Smart cache" for style sheets and "Smart cache" for JavaScript code

Answer (score -2):

You compressor to reduce the lines of codes present in your JS & css. There are lots of online minifier available over internet. Try to use their services.